# Force Python empty split algorithm with known separators

Tags: python, split

Fixing a bug in my code I recently figured out that Python has two very different split algorithms.

One is used when no separator is provided like in:

```
>>> '  a  b  c  '.split()
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

In other words it splits on any sequence of predefined blank characters and ignore leading and trailing blanks.

The other one is used when a separator list is provided, like in:

```
>>> '  a  b  c  '.split(' ')
['', '', 'a', '', 'b', '', 'c', '', '']
```

This one splits on every single occurence of the separator string.

You may notice than the two algorithms are really very different. The first one won't ever create an empty string in the result list for instance, the other one is inversible and can can be inverted using `sep.join(list)` which is not true of the version without arguments.

That's slightly annoying to have two very different functions called by the same name, but I can understand the rationale.

But is there any simple way to force the use of the first algorithm when I have a different set of separators than the default one ?

My use case is that I have input strings also containing other valid separators (in my case '\0').

```
>>> ' a \0 b \0 c \0 '.split()
['a', '\x00', 'b', '\x00', 'c', '\x00']
```

Not good, \0 is not taken as blank separator

```
>>> ' a \0 b \0 c \0 '.split('\0')
[' a ', ' b ', ' c ', ' ']
```

Not good ' ' is left in the splitted strings

```
>>> ' a \0 b \0 c \0 '.split('\0 ')
[' a ', 'b ', 'c ', '']
```

Splits on sequences of \0 followed by space, not what I want

The best I've found so far is the code below:

```
>>> import re
>>> [x for x in re.split(' |\0',' a \0 b c \0 c \0 ') if x]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
```

It works and does what I want, but it looks way overkill.

Is there either a simpler way to do that ? Or a way to configure what python uses as default separators list in split() without arguments ?

Answer (score 4):

You could turn your logic around, telling the regex to find everything that's not a separator:

```
>>> re.findall('[^ \0]+',' a \0 b c \0 c \0 ')
['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all the string's `\0` characters with whitespace before the `split()`:

```
>>> ' a \0 b \0 c \0 '.replace('\0', ' ').split()
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Thanks, it's much simpler than mine. Still it's copying the string twice.

Comment: Yes, it does have to perform the `replace()` and then process the string again for the `split()`, but I wouldn't worry about that until it starts to cause unacceptable performance problems for your project.

Comment: I agree. At least it does not have to import re. I wouldn't care about performance issue. But it will work only as long as \t or \n are also accepted separator (which is ok for me).

Comment: Well, your question did say that you wanted to add valid separators to the default, which is the effect that this answer accomplishes, so it seems fine. :)